# How to find if we passed a day when adding minutes to datetime object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a date range from June 21 to Jun 27.I want to add 20 minutes to my start date every 5secs and make a service call to get some values. Also, for the second service call I need my previous end datetime as start datetime.For example for service call 1, 
my start date is Jun 21, 5:00 PM
my end date is  Jun 27, 5:20 PM
my second service call should have 
start date as Jun 21, 5:20 PM
end date as Jun 21 , 5:40 PM
How can I achieve this through javascript and also how do I change date once     I pass  24 hrs.
    Thanks!

```
//My start date and end date
var startDt = newDate(data.startDate);
var endDt   = newDate(data.endDate);

var count = 0;
setInterval(function()
{

   if(count == 0){
   var sDt= new Date(startDt).toISOString();
   var eDt= new Date(startDt.setMinutes(startDt.getMinutes() +    10)).toISOString();
       }
   else{
   var sDt = new Date(startDt.setMinutes(startDt.getMinutes() +  )).toISOString();
}
//calling my apy with sDt and eDt here;
count++;
},5000)
```

Comment: Questions on SO are to help when you get stuck with a problem.  Go ahead and try to solve this yourself.  If you get an error or get stuck on a specific conceptual topic, come back and ask about it.

Comment: I am stuck on how to do this , that is the reason I am seeking help here !

Comment: Ok.  What have you tried then?  Can you provide us with some code snippets of your attempts?

Comment: Should your second service call example be: 
start date as Jun 27, 5:20 PM end date as Jun 27, 5:40 PM ?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. When you add 20 minutes to a `DateTime`, it will automatically go to the next date when it passes midnight.

Comment: The date issue is solved but for some reason the time increment still has an issue i see some duplicate values not sure whats wrong 2016-05-22T00:10:00.000Z
2016-05-22T00:20:00.000Z
2016-05-21T23:50:00.000Z
2016-05-22T00:00:00.000Z
 2016-05-21T23:50:00.000Z
2016-05-22T00:00:00.000Z
2016-05-22T00:20:00.000Z
2016-05-22T00:30:00.000Z
2016-05-22T00:00:00.000Z
2016-05-22T00:10:00.000Z
2016-05-22T00:00:00.000Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javascript `setMinutes()` method will automatically go to the next hour or day when the minutes or hour wrap around.

```
startTime = new Date(endTime); // Copy old endTime to startTime
endTime.setMinutes(endTime.getMinutes() + 20); // add 20 minutes to endTime
```

Here's the full code:

```
//My start date and end date
var startDt = newDate(data.startDate);
var endDt   = newDate(data.endDate);

var count = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function()
{
    if (new Date() > endDt) { // Reached the endDt
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }
    var sDt = new Date(startDt).toISOString();
    var eDt = new Date(startDt.setMinutes(startDt.getMinutes() + 20)).toISOString();
    //calling my apy with sDt and eDt here;
    count++;
},5000)
```

Comment: I have tried this Barmar but after my service call is made with my startDate as 5:10 and endDate 5:20  and when I have to pass my new values for my startTime and endTime before it gives my startTime as undefined after the api call when I am copying the previous endTime

Comment: That sounds like a scope problem. Make sure they're global variables so they'll persist from one call to the next.

Comment: Yeah but problem is I am getting my values for the startdate and enddate from another api so how can I make them global variables? They have to be inside my first api call where i am receiving them right ?

Comment: No, they can stil be global variables, which the first API call assigns and then starts the interval timer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run a function every five seconds

```
var dt = new Date(2016,6,21)

setTimeOut(function(){
//add 20 minutes to dt
dt = new Date(dt.getTime()+(20*60000)) // dt will be your start time
//end time is add 20 minutes to start time
var endDT = new Date(dt.getTime()+(20*60000));

//now call you ajax, return what ever you need along with dt and endDT

},5000//five seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to add seconds to your startDate like this

```
var startDate = moment('Jun 21, 5:00 PM');
startDate.add('20','minutes');
```

it will automatically maintain the coherence of the timestamps

Comment: Thanks Tiago! I am not using moment.js for several reasons!